# Implementing `and` and `or`

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

I implemented `and` and `or`:

```
-- or is like and, only it returns True if 
-- any of the boolean values in a list is True.
or' :: [Bool] -> Bool
or' []     = False
or' (x:xs) = x || or' xs 

--and takes a list of boolean values and returns True only if 
-- all the values in the list are True.
and' :: [Bool] -> Bool
and' [] = False
and' (x:xs) = x && and' xs
```

Is pattern matching the most elegant solution here?

Also, should `or' []` and `and' []` return `False`? It makes sense for them to do so when passing in a non-null input.

Example: `or' [False, False]`

But, how about the behavior of `or' []` or `and' []`? Does `False` make sense here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `or'` function is fine.

`and' []` should return `True` — that's what the built-in `and []` does.  As it is, your `and'` function is broken, and always returns `False`:

> ```
> *Main> and' [True]
> False
> ```

Answer (score 8):

Consider that `Bool` is an algebraic data structure like any other in Haskell. Pattern matching is the most elegant solution, but you can use even more of it to be even more elegant!

```
-- import Prelude hiding (or)

or :: [Bool] -> Bool
or []         = False
or (False:bs) = or bs
or (True :_ ) = True
```

Comment: I like that this solution works based on first principles, not even relying on `||` and `&&`.

Answer (score 4):

> Also, should `or' []` and `and' []` return False? It makes sense for them to do so when passing in a non-null input.

No, it makes sense only for `or'`. Apart from translating them to basic mathematic quantifiers "Is any of the items true?" (`False` for no items) and "Are all of the items true?" (`True` for no items), you can try to evaluate your function with an example one-item list and confirm whether it meets the expected results:

```
or' [False]       = False
False || or' []   = False
False || False    = True
--       ^^^^^

and' [True]       = True
True && and' []   = True
True &&  True     = True
--       ^^^^
```

> Is pattern matching the most elegant solution here?

It's OK, but most recursive functions can be written more concisely (= elegant?) with folds:

```
or' = foldr (||) False
and' = foldr (&&) True
```